# How can I install OpenSolaris without Graphical Environment - just text console?

Tags: command-line, installation, ssh, window-manager, opensolaris

I would like to install OpenSolaris and use it as a home-server. I will interact with it just with SSH, so I don't need the Graphical Environment. How can I install OpenSolaris without the Graphical Environment?

And preferably I would like to use the SSH-interface as much as possible, is it even possible to do the installation over SSH? I tried the SSH-boot alternative on the installation-CD, then I have to use a password, but I have no password since I haven't installed the system yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a graphical environment, installing over SSH would be a little difficult as OpenSolaris doesn't have a text-based installer at this time (if I recall correctly). You could always boot the installation into text mode, then just enable SSH.

If you want to do the installation over SSH, you'd have to use the graphical install with `ssh -X`. Once logged in you can then run `pfexec /usr/bin/gui-install`.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but is it possible to use the graphical installer but just install a text-based OpenSolaris system? since I don't need a graphical environment?

Comment: I don't think so. You can probably remove it with pkgrm though. If a smaller install is what you're after, check out Milax: http://www.milax.org/ . I think you can install it to a drive with some tinkering rather than just running it live.

Comment: You could also look at the instructions at http://briancline.org/read/file_server_3_tweaking_opensolaris . I haven't tried this myself (yet).

Answer (score 1):

The OpenSolaris LiveCD always installs exactly what's on the LiveCD, including the GUI environment.

There is a text-mode installer under development for headless servers, which does not
use a GUI to install, nor does it install the GUI - [a prototype is available to download now](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+caiman/Text+Install+b134+Notes).

You can also use the [Automated Installer](http://hub.opensolaris.org/bin/view/Project+caiman/auto_install), which is more like the traditional Solaris Jumpstart - it does not use a GUI and installs just the set of packages you specify in the manifest you provide to it.  [The AI guide](http://dlc.sun.com/osol/docs/content/2009.06/AIinstall/) explains with a lot more detail.